# What does this do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

```
gsub(/^/, "\t" * num)
```

What character is being substituted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No character is being substituted, it is just inserting `num` tabs at the beginning so you could say that it is substituting the zero width "beginning of line" marker. Whoever wrote that would have been better off with something more like this:

```
tabbed = "\t" * num + original
```

A regular expression really isn't the right tool for simple string concatenation.

**Clarification:** If you're expecting your string to contain multiple lines then using:

```
gsub(/^/, "\t" * num)
```

to prefix all the lines with tabs is a reasonably thing to do and less noisy than splitting, prefixing, and re-joining. If you're only expecting to deal with a single line in your string then simple string concatenation would be the better choice.

Answer (score 5):

`^` means "start of line" in regex syntax, so this will insert `num` tab characters at the beginning of every line. Technically you could say that it replaces the empty string at the start of every line.